# select in jqgrid disappeared when I click next page

Tags: select, jqgrid

I use select control in jqgrid like this

{name:'skill',index:'skill', width:100, align:"center", editable:true, edittype:"select"},

skill values in variable.

var skillCode = '<%=skillStr%>';

so, I set value after loading grid.

loadComplete: function() {
    jQuery('#gridList').setColProp('skill', {formatter:'select', editoptions: { value: skillCode} });
}

it works fine, but when I click next page or click header in order to sort...
select value disappeared.

How do I display select value in case click next page or sort header??

thanks in advance.

Comment: What you mean under "select value disappeared"? What is example of the value of the `skillCode` variable? Why you set it inside of `loadComplete` instead of the usage directly at the definition of the `'skill'` column?

Comment: @Oleg my grid is edit mode so I populate select value dynamically. value came from server and I put it to skillCode variable. this is an example code "00001:LOW;00002:MID;00003:HIGH;00004:EXP".

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
Problem is column name in jqgrid and jsonstring column name are different.
fix the jqgrid column name with db column name then it works fine.

{name:'skillCode',index:'skillCode', width:100, align:"center", editable:true, edittype:"select", formatter:'select', editoptions:{value:skillCode}},

actual column name is not skill but skillCode.

thanks all.